# How do I show the equation formula again instead of its number of ref?

Tags: equations

I have an equation:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:equation}
f(x)=x
\end{equation}
```

I would like to refer to this equation and show the whole formula again, and not only its number. In other words, I wanna get `$f(x)=x$` instead of `\eqref{eq:equation}`.

How do I refer to the equation in order to reproduce its formula instead of its number?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: A tip: indent with 4 spaces the code block to format it properly or use the button with the braces (`{}`) above the edit window. In the case of inline code, either put the code between backticks (`) or select and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: The answer to the question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47570/newtoks-token-seems-to-have-local-scope suggests a way to write a command that "remembers" text in one place to use in another. It might work for you if you don't need to do it often. For a systematic solution, you will  have to wait for one of the regulars here to chip in.

Comment: I guess this answer is what you wanted. It used the least additional mechanisms compared to the existing solutions under the current question.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67654/286722

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found this question that was asked earlier: [Is it possible to re-insert a LaTeX equation by label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63699/is-it-possible-to-re-insert-a-latex-equation-by-label)

It cites [*"Equation Reuse"*](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=8275) from [LaTeX-Community Forum](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/) as a solution.

Namely:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%defining the box
\newsavebox\myeq
%filling the box
\savebox\myeq{\vbox{\begin{align*}
  a &= b\\
  &= c\\
  &= d\\
  &= e\\
  &= f
\end{align*}}}

%using the box
\usebox\myeq

%using the box
\usebox\myeq

%using the box
\usebox\myeq

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works pretty well. I would like to turn off the numbering when I use equation or align instead of align*. For instance, the first time the equation apear, I want to number it. The next time it apears, I want turn off the number. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You could have the first instance be in the `equation` environment and define a separate box with the equation in `displaymath`. It's not a great solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 15):

This might be a solution, but I don't see how it would help the reader.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\repeatable}[2]{%
  \label{#1}\global\@namedef{repeatable@#1}{#2}#2
}
\newcommand{\eqrepeat}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{repeatable@#1}{NOT FOUND}{$\@nameuse{repeatable@#1}$}%
  ~\eqref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\repeatable{eq:good}{f(x)=x}
\end{equation}

This is seen in \eqrepeat{eq:good}.

\end{document}
```

However it seems from your comments that you want something more complicated; please be more specific in your question.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I just want to repeat the function of equation. Your answer worked well. Do you know how to hide the number not in the main equation, but when I am referring to that in the text? Thanks.

Comment: @Diogo Use `equation*`. But I don't find particular merits in the practice of repeating the whole equation; to be honest I consider it heavy.

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this: When `\repeatable` contains a `tikzcd`-environment, I had to add `[ampersand replacement=\&]` to `tikzcd` to avoid the error `Undefined control sequence. \end{tikzcd}}`. I'd love to know why!

Comment: @egreg One reason I see for repeating equations is a "cheat sheet" at the end of an equation-heavy document.

Comment: @Anna It’s because the material is read as the argument to another command.

Comment: I have tried to adjust this solution to `align` environments by changing `eqrepeat` to

`\newcommand{\eqrepeat}[1]{%
        \@ifundefined{repeatable@#1}{NOT FOUND}{\begin{align*}\@nameuse{repeatable@#1}\tag{\ref{#1}}\end{align*}}}`

Unfortunately, that leads to `label multiply defined` warnings, even though I don't see how/why my definition reuses the label anywhere... ((Otherwise, it works well.))