# Is it possible to reprint an equation without actually rewriting it?

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, numbering

I have an equation like:

```
\begin{equation} \label{whatever}
x+y=1
\end{equation}
```

I want to write it again, keeping the same number. I know I could do the following:

```
\begin{equation} 
x+y=1 \tag{\ref{whatever}}
\end{equation}
```

However, I would like to get the same outcome without rewriting the full equation. The reason is that I may change the first equation, and I would like the change to be automatically applied to all the cases in which the equation is repeated.
I.e. I'd like to have something like

```
\begin{equation} 
\rewrite{whatever} \tag{\ref{whatever}}
\end{equation}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Related: [Recalling a theorem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51286/5764)

Comment: why not just define the equation code as a named macro?  you'd still have to label and tag it separately, but the contents would have to be written only once.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87095/5049