# Repeat entire table

Tags: tables

Is there a method to repeat an entire table? I've defined a custom table format using xparse and I have potentially ~50 of these custom tables. I would like to create an appendix of the tables, including all content. I don't want to duplicate the content as it's changing frequently

EDIT: One solution is to use a separate file and include it multiple times. This is not a great solution as some of my "tables" are really only 2-3 rows long, and I have a large number of them anyway (e.g. ~50 separate include files would be much harder to work with than the current inline tables)

Comment: You could store them in macros maybe using similar techniques as discussed here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87095/5049

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using [`filecontents`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package? This method essentially creates separate file but is much easier to handle. Check the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{mytable.tex}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{c}r}
Team              & P & W & D & L & F  & A & Pts \\
\hline
Manchester United & 6 & 4 & 0 & 2 & 10 & 5 & 12  \\
Celtic            & 6 & 3 & 0 & 3 &  8 & 9 &  9  \\
Benfica           & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  7 & 8 &  7  \\
FC Copenhagen     & 6 & 2 & 1 & 3 &  5 & 8 &  7  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{filecontents}

\input{mytable.tex}

\input{mytable.tex}

\input{mytable.tex}

\input{mytable.tex}

\end{document}
```

and its result:[image]

Of course, you can combine this package with other ones, such as [`ltxtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable), to enhance the result, as suggested by the package document.

Tabular example taken from [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).

Comment: This looks perfect!! I have to wait until I'm home to try it out

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package; define a collection using `\definecollection{<name>}` and then wrap your tables using the `collect*` environment; then simply include your collection in the appendix using `\includecollection{<name>}`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collect}

\definecollection{mytables}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}

\begin{collect*}{mytables}{}{\par\bigskip}{}{}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}
\toprule
Header1 & Header 2 & Header3 \\
\midrule
column1a & column2a & column 3a \\
column1b & column2b & column 3b \\
column1c & column2c & column 3c \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{collect*}

\begin{collect*}{mytables}{}{\par\bigskip}{}{}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{*{2}{l}}
\toprule
Header1 & Header 2 \\
\midrule
column1a & column2a \\
column1b & column2b \\
column1c & column2c \\
column1d & column2d \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{collect*}

\section{Appendix}
\includecollection{mytables}

\end{document}
```

[image]