# Alternative eqref command (generating a footnote)

Tags: macros, equations, cross-referencing, footnotes

Sometimes I think it is helpful to have a visual reference to a cited equation, besides its reference number. Let me give a (manual) example of what I'm talking about:

```
\begin{document}
(...)

\begin{equation}\label{1.1}
  y=x
\end{equation}

<several pages later>

... in equation \eqref{1.1}\footnote{y=x} ...
\end{document}
```

I'd like to create a command that makes this process automatically. Something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\eqref{#1}\footnote{eqcont}}
```

where the 'eqcont' part is a call to the contents of the equation environment. However, I can't figure out a code to do this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! This question and its answers might be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although @cgnieder s comment could be very helpful, I think the focus of the question is slightly different and needs further treatment.

The `environ` package is very helpful here. It allows you to redefine `\eqref` exactly as you intended it to be, where 'eqcont' had to be changed a little:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{refeq}[1]{%
  \label{#1}
  \begin{equation} \BODY \end{equation}
  \expandafter\xdef\csname eq#1\endcsname{\BODY}
  }
\let\AMSeqref\eqref
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\aftergroup\AMSeqref{#1}\footnote{\csname eq#1\endcsname}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[8]
\begin{refeq}{1.1}
  y=x
\end{refeq}
\lipsum
... in equation \eqref{1.1} ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... which is why I only commented :)

Comment: Thanks you guys! Actually, I'm learning a lot trying to solve this command and the refeq environment works like a charm. Regards!

Comment: @JGSeg [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.